# Equivalent norms with a specific restriction to a subspace.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X=(V,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be a normed space and $W$ a subspace of $V$. Suppose $\vert \cdot \vert$ is a norm on $W$ which is equivalent to the restriction of $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ to $W$.

I would like to prove that there exists a norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ on $V$ that is equivalent to $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ and whose restriction to $W$ is equal to $\vert \cdot \vert$. This is an exercise of Linear Analysis - Béla Bollobás, Chapter 2.

My first idea was writing $V$ as direct sum $V=W \oplus U$ and defining $\Vert w+u \Vert_1 := \vert w \vert + \Vert u \Vert$. However, I could not prove this would be equivalent to $\Vert \cdot \Vert$. Does anyone have an idea how to proceed?

Comment: Probably not what you were hoping for but there is an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2457415/144766

Comment: Your idea cannot work if $W$ is not a [complemented subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_subspace).